# Switching tabs not working on click of tabs with SlidingtabLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/PrimaryColor"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
    />
```

The sliding tabs works fine on tabs swipe, but it is not working on tab click. Tab lick doesn't swipe you to the relevant tab content.
Below is MainActivity.java is where i am working on viewpager and SlidingTabLayout:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    //Declaring All The Variables Needed
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       /*
        Assigning view variables to their respective view in xml
        by findViewByID method
         */

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        /*
        Creating Adapter and setting that adapter to the viewPager
        setSupportActionBar method takes the toolbar and sets it as
        the default action bar thus making the toolbar work like a normal
        action bar.
         */
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        /*
        TabLayout.newTab() method creates a tab view, Now a Tab view is not the view
        which is below the tabs, its the tab itself.
         */

        final TabLayout.Tab tasbih1 = tabLayout.newTab();
        final TabLayout.Tab tasbih2 = tabLayout.newTab();
        final TabLayout.Tab tasbih3 = tabLayout.newTab();
        final TabLayout.Tab tasbih4 = tabLayout.newTab();

        /*
        Setting Title text for our tabs respectively
         */

        tasbih1.setText("تسبيح");
        tasbih2.setText("إستغفار");
        tasbih3.setText("عدد الركعات");
        tasbih4.setText("إتجاه القبلة");

        /*
        Adding the tab view to our tablayout at appropriate positions
        As I want home at first position I am passing home and 0 as argument to
        the tablayout and like wise for other tabs as well
         */
        tabLayout.addTab(tasbih1, 0);
        tabLayout.addTab(tasbih2, 1);
        tabLayout.addTab(tasbih3, 2);
        tabLayout.addTab(tasbih4, 3);


        /*
        TabTextColor sets the color for the title of the tabs, passing a ColorStateList here makes
        tab change colors in different situations such as selected, active, inactive etc

        TabIndicatorColor sets the color for the indiactor below the tabs
         */

        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.drawable.tab_selector));
        tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.indicator));

        /*
        Adding a onPageChangeListener to the viewPager
        1st we add the PageChangeListener and pass a TabLayoutPageChangeListener so that Tabs Selection
        changes when a viewpager page changes.
         */

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));




        /*
        SensorManager mSensorManager;

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        if (mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) != null){
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Magnetic sensor exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Magnetic sensor doesn't exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        */
    }

    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Post your code and if any stack trace then post that also.

Comment: Check my updated question.

Comment: Add this on `onCreate` `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);`.

Comment: Thanks man it works fine to me now !

Answer (score 8):

Try below one if your tab is not focusing on the front.

```
findViewById(R.id.tabs).bringToFront();
```

Also, I think you forgot to use.

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Comment: This way TabLayout will overlap ViewPager. This is not solving the problem, but giving ad hoc solution.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following override method.

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

});
```

Comment: This is depreciated now

Answer (score 2):

**I Faced The same problem, I Solved it By 
 `android:layout_below="@+id/sliding_tabs"` on ViewPager and  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` on `SlidingTablayout`**

```
    <com.androidbegin.pagertabstriptutorial.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">        
    </com.androidbegin.pagertabstriptutorial.SlidingTabLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Activity` or `Fragment` class if not add -

```
TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(ViewPager);
```

In this case when you are swiping, your tab won't be changing, only `ViewPager`. For other case you will have to post your code

Comment: Ya you have not added the line
`tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);`

Add it at the end of `onCreate()` method

Answer (score 1):

you can check in your xml if viewpager is not overlap your tablayout . if overlap then tab select not wrok

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before.

Even if a `ViewPager` isn't overlapping your tabs (as other answers have suggested), it's possible that *some* element is overlapping. In my experience, many times, a `Toolbar` is the culprit.

First, take a look at this layout, and make sure you have something like it. Especially take note of the `TabLayout`'s properties:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabMode="scrollable">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab_home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_home" />
<!-- And so on, with more tabs... -->
```

Once you have something like the above, make sure you have the appropriate code in the corresponding activity's `onCreate` method. Something like this should work:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        final TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        final ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                // Nothing needed here.
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                // Nothing needed here.
            }
        });
    }
```

Note that in that code, I use a custom `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, `PagerAdapter`. You can use whatever pager adapter you'd like.

Answer (score -1):

Happened the same th to me. I fixed it with

```
android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
```